# Display mathjax output in realtime

Tags: javascript, jquery, mathjax

How do I modify this mathjax example to live preview while I type? Right now it only displays result after I have pressed enter. I would like to tweak it so that it works similar to how stackoverflow/math.stackexchange shows the preview when typing a question.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>MathJax Dynamic Math Test Page</title>

<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
  MathJax.Hub.Config({
    tex2jax: {
      inlineMath: [["$","$"],["\\(","\\)"]]
    }
  });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML-full">
</script>

</head>
<body>

<script>
  //
  //  Use a closure to hide the local variables from the
  //  global namespace
  //
  (function () {
    var QUEUE = MathJax.Hub.queue;  // shorthand for the queue
    var math = null;                // the element jax for the math output.

    //
    //  Get the element jax when MathJax has produced it.
    //
    QUEUE.Push(function () {
      math = MathJax.Hub.getAllJax("MathOutput")[0];
    });

    //
    //  The onchange event handler that typesets the
    //  math entered by the user
    //
    window.UpdateMath = function (TeX) {
      QUEUE.Push(["Text",math,"\\displaystyle{"+TeX+"}"]);
    }
  })();
</script>

Type some TeX code:
<input id="MathInput" size="50" onchange="UpdateMath(this.value)" />
<p>

<div id="MathOutput">
You typed: ${}$
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: yeah, because `onchange` only fires when the enter key is pressed or when the field is blurred.

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down/ for migration tips.

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger What is the best way to show live preview of MathJax in a wordpress site which has input field for writing question/comments with math formulas. For absolute beginner, please guide "what" and "where" to type some script, if any. Thanks

Comment: @think123 What is the best way to show live preview of MathJax in a wordpress site which has input field for writing question/comments with math formulas. For absolute beginner, please guide "what" and "where" to type some script, if any. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of using `onchange` try `onkeypress` or `onkeyup`.

`onchange` is only triggered when you leave the field, but the others (obviously) happen with each key-stroke.

Comment: What is the best way to show live preview of MathJax in a wordpress site which has input field for writing question/comments with math formulas. For absolute beginner, please guide "what" and "where" to type some script, if any. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you are using Internet Explorer, which doesn't fire `onchange` events as often or efficiently as other browsers.

The version in the [MathJax Examples](http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/test/sample-dynamic.html) includes more code to handle IE better. You might want to look at the source code there for details.

Comment: this isn't actually true, in fact.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
  MathJax.Hub.Config({tex2jax: {inlineMath: [ ['$','$'], ["\\(","\\)"] ],processEscapes: true}});
</script>

<script
  type="text/javascript"
  charset="utf-8"
  src="https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML">
</script>

<script>
function f() {
  var input = document.getElementById("input");
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = input.value;
  MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub]);
  }
</script>

<textarea id="input" cols="25" rows="5" onkeyup="f()">
</textarea>

<p id="output"></p>
```