# Recognize when writing in between two $$ signs

Tags: jquery, mathjax

I have a textfield in which I'm writing some text.

For the sake of simplicity, I want that `alert('Boom!')` jumps out every time I start writing in between two $$.

For example I have a blank textfield and start typing (cursor is "|" sign)

```
Today is a really nice day|
```

nothing happens, start typing

```
Today is a really nice day, $|$
```

still nothing, but now when I start typing

```
Today is a really nice day, $someText|$
```

alert box should jump out for each letter in between those dollar signs.

Why do I need that kind of feature? I want live-equation-preview (MathJax rendering) every time user starts typing his/her equation, and I can recognize it's an equation by $$ signs (everything in between is rendered).

**EDIT:** Multiple $$'s are possible in textfield. Script must recognize the one which is currently active (cursor position is between it's $$'s).

Comment: what have u tried so far? show us ur code?

Comment: sounds like a job for Regular Expressions

Comment: @soul I don't have any because I really don't know where to start (except manually check char by char forward and backward and catching '$' if found any, but what if I have textarea with over few thousand characters and no $$ in it at all).

Comment: @j_mcnally How could I use it in relation with cursor position?

Comment: @svenkapudija use keyup function and find a $ sign

Comment: @soul Added EDIT part. Maybe something like: 1.) find first $ 2.) find second $ (one pair) 3.) test if cursor position is in between, if yes copy that text, else repeat the proces. But like I said, performance issue (because that would be called on every single keyup)?

Comment: $(f1Selector).on("change keyup mouseup cut paste", function() { something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery caret plugin

http://examplet.buss.hk/download/download.php?plugin=caret.1.01

*note: edit and delete these characters **Ôªø** from line 8*

and `replace` funcition. ( not to replace anything but to use the index of matched pattern )

```
$("#myText").bind("keyup", function(e){
     var text = $(this).val();
     var caret = $(this).caret().start;

     if(text && text.length > 0){
        text.replace(/\$.*?\$/g, function(m, n){
           if(caret > n && caret < (n + m.length)){
              alert("BOOM");
           }
        });
     }
});
```

demo : http://jsfiddle.net/xqXXb/

Just showing how to do it. You can improve this.

use

```
$("#myText").bind("keyup keydown change", function(e){ ...
```

for a better result.

Comment: It works! But only for the first occurrence. If I continue writing and after the first $$ pair add another one - it's not recognized at all. Maybe do some recursion with the text after the first pair (if caret is not found in it)?

Comment: Works as a charm (connected with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7925622/display-mathjax-output-in-realtime). Thanks.

Comment: Also, as a "bonus", how to search (which regex) for the same thing but instead $ and $, signs would be \[ and \] ? I have problems with escaping those. It's used in MathJax for centered, separated equations.

Comment: just replace $, so it becomes `/\[.*?\]/g`

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice that SO also escaped them. It should be \\[ and \\].