# RegEx - text between \[ and \]

Tags: javascript, regex

I had the same question with `$$` signs ([question with $$](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9649857/recognize-when-writing-in-between-two-signs)), but can't  get it to work (same code) with `\[` and `\]` signs. I need regex pattern to recognize when I'm inside those signs (I can have multiple ones in the same text, they all should be covered).

```
text.replace(/\$.*?\$/g, function(m, n){
    if(caret > n && caret < (n + m.length)){
        alert("BOOM");
    }
});
```

So `/\$.*?\$/g` should become something else so it recognizes when I'm inside `\[` and `\]` signs. Regular replacing doesn't work (`/\\[.*?\\]/g`).

Also `\[some\thing\]` should work - it should select `some\thing` (\ shouldn't make any troubles).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to match `\[` literally, you have to escape both characters, `\` and `[`, thus it becomes `\\\[` (the same for `\]`).

**In general:** Whenever you want to match a character with a special meaning, you have to escape it with `\`.

But note that the backslash is the escape character in strings as well. So if you defined a string as:

```
"\[some\thing\]"
```

the actual value is

```
"[some  hing]"
```

(`\t` is a tab)

You'd have to escape `\` here as well:

```
"\\[some\\thing\\]"
//  "\[some\thing\]"
```

So before you think about a regular expression, double check the actual input.

Comment: What if I have \\[some{newline}text\\] ?

Comment: What do you want to know? Do you want to extract `some{newline}text`? Is `{newline}` to be taken literally or do you mean the new line character `\n`?

Comment: I mean \n or \r. Yes, I want it to work the same way. So if I have in textfield \\[some\ntext\\] (across two lines) it should also get recognized.

Comment: You can use `[\s\S]` instead of `.` to match white space and non white space characters. [From MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp):  *(The decimal point) matches any single character except the newline characters: `\n`, `\r`, `\u2028` or `\u2029`. (`[\s\S]` can be used to match any character including newlines.)*.

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
/\\\[(.*?)\\\]/g
```